# Angular jasmine unit test Login authentication landing controller not initiated

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

As I have a problem for the loginpage(Login controller) with specs that login using the credentials and all my test cases for Login controller run successfully.But after login the page redirected to the landing page and the landing page namely the landing controller got undefined.the controller itself not getting initiated during the specs loads.could any one provide suggestion on this query?

How to test John papa vm.model unit testing with jasmine?

```
    (function () {
       'use strict';
       angular
        .module('MYApp')
          .controller("TestController", TestController);

   function testController() {

var vm = this;

vm.model = {


name: "controllerAs vm test"

};}

  })();

  describe('Controller: testController', function() {

   beforeEach(module('myApp'));

   var testController;

   beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
    scope = {};

     testController = $controller('testController', {});

    }));

   it('should have model defined and testController.model.name is equal        to controllerAs vm test', function() {
expect(testController).toBeDefined();
expect(testController.model).toBeDefined();
expect(testController.model.name).toEqual("controllerAs vm test");
   });

     it('should not have a property called vm', function() {
expect(testController.vm).toBeUndefined();
     });
     });
```

Always the controller is not initiated in the spec,

getting an error message :

TestController 
Controller: testController 
undefined at TestController (C:/wwwroot/js/test.controller.js:9:2976) at e (C:/wwwroot/lib/angular/angular.min.js:39:399) at instantiate (C:/wwwroot/lib/angular/angular.min.js:40:10) at C:/wwwroot/lib/angular/angular.min.js:80:453 at C:/wwwroot/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2170:21 at C:/wwwroot/app/home/test.controller.spec.js:10:37 at e (C:/wwwroot/lib/angular/angular.min.js:39:399) at workFn (C:/wwwroot/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2810:26)

Expected undefined to be defined. at C:/wwwroot/app/test/test.controller.spec.js:151:49 
TypeError: undefined is not an object 
(evaluating 'testcontroller.model') in C:/wwwroot/app/test/test.controller.spec.js(line 152) at C:/wwwroot/app/test/test.controller.spec.js:152:36

Comment: can you please add some code example?

Comment: could you please share some sample example with Login page application with specs that redirect to the page after successful authentication without using scope objects using Angular js?

Comment: Please any one provide suggestion or solution that will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How to test John papa vm.model unit testing with jasmine?

Comment: As I have provided a code example that clearly explains my problem.please provide your optimal solution for this issue. I'm facing this issue last one month and still cant able to solve this.please any one suggestion is greatly appreciated

Comment: "Expecting undefined to be defined" is a clue.

Comment: So here the controller itself not injecting inside the spec.thats the reason it returns undefined error message.please anyone provide a solution that will be greatly appreciated.